# Update Manager is in Launcher and Alt-Tab list, but I can't switch to it

Tags: launcher, update-manager

The Update Manager recently started itself and found two updates.  I can tell by the icon in the launcher.  The icon has a (2) on it and a little white arrow saying the application is running.  I can also see the update-manager process in a 'ps -A' list.  Alt-Tab also shows the Update Manager.

The problem is I can't get Update Manager to show up.  If I click on the icon or Alt-Tab to it, nothing happens.  I've never had any issues starting it manually, but when it starts on it's own after finding an update, I can't switch to it.

What can I try to make this work better?

Comment: this is still true of 12.04.1

Comment: @AdamDymitruk I am thinking this could be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/925260) with no known workarounds.

Comment: Can be something related to the workspaces? Sometimes some applications are shown as to be in one workspace while actually they are on another... But maybe yours is a completely separate issue ;)

Comment: *@AdamDymitruk said (converted from an edit suggestion):* the bug mentioned in one of the answers is not it. You /can/ select update manager with Alt+Tab, but it does not come up. Even pressing it's icon with the mouse does not bring up the the window. This may not be a unity bug but in fact an update manager bug. No other application behaves like this.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk This may not be [that bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/925260), but it still seems to be **a bug**. So [the bounty should probably be refunded, and this question closed](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/4216/22949). (If it's a different bug then it wouldn't necessarily have status Confirmed, but I think that meta consensus would still apply. You could post on meta to discuss this variation, though.) Anyone who experiences this problem can be the one to [file the bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) for it.

Comment: Lame. Question closed.

Comment: Makes me want to avoid  this site.

Comment: Funny how only now, after I posted bounty, does this question get closed.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I didn't find this specific issue on launchpad either. For me, even though the update manager doesn't completely open, it still can be closed from the "x" on the top right panel or ctrl+q. Once closed it reopens fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem with libreoffice.

You can use 'super + w'. You will get all the window on screen, click the window you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Unity, it seems to happen with LibreOffice too. I don't think there is any fix yet, Unity is still being worked on. Link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/942222

You can just update manually using a terminal by typing these in sequence:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If the update manager is bugging you, kill it with this command:

```
killall update-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen scenarios where application windows end up outside of the screen area. Sometimes its caused by having windows placed on secondary screens then disconnecting the screen. Leaving the application "unreachable"

- Go to the desktop that seems to have the application running.
- Make sure the application is selected with alt+tab.
- Press alt+space + m (m for move, if you use english ubuntu) drag the
  mouse cursor to the    center of the screen.

Your application window should be attached to
   the mouse cursor if the issue you had was this.

Comment: will try this when it comes up